# StartupAbortedException when opening any android studio project

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio was working too slow and gradle build was taking more than 15 minutes. In frustration I powered off my computer mid gradle build. When I restarted android studio later, it has corrupted and I am getting the following error:

`.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: CPP_SUPPORT_DISABLED`

How do I rectify this?

Comment: do you using java 8 and how much ram you are using.?

Comment: I do have it and have 4gb ram

Comment: actually recommended ram is 8gb, so this is may it was working slow. and in this error if you try to update your android studio may will work.

Comment: unfortunately it was the updated version- so it refused to get updated again

Comment: then i can suggest you to reinstall studio to solve but remove it from the system thoroughly and restart your system once then install it again

Answer (score 0):

When NDK Support plugin is disabled and NDK Workspace manager support is disabled then it starts working